# How to run a github action step if it has a label

Tags: github, github-actions

How would I check for a label added on a pull request when I merge to main branch from a pull request.
I tried using the below but didn't work:

```
name: Publish
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  Publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
     if: ${{github.event.label.name == 'release'}}
     .......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about like this?

```yaml
name: Create Release
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
    types:
      - closed

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 5
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true && contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'release') # detect when pull request is merged since there's no merged event. 
    steps:
    - name: Create release
...
```

Comment: Thanks @banyan, I was hoping to have it on the push ?  What’s the timeout 5 minutes for ?

Comment: push event isn't associated with the `label`. to have the label, it needs to be either issue or pull_request. Sorry, timeout-minutes was irrelevant in this context.  the timeout for github actions is 6 hours by default, so if a job isn't stopped, it will consume time, so I always keep it on.

Comment: The if doesn't seem to work. github.event.pull_request.merged == true && github.event.label.name == 'release'

Comment: When I echo out what the label name is its empty.

Comment: @me-me sorry,  made a mistake. Updated the answer to use `contains`.